# Deutsche Übersetzung von "policy"

Tags: translation

Wie kann man das englische Wort "policy" ins Deutsche übersetzen?

Z.B. bei den Folgenden:

> The company's policy requires a,b,c.

> This is against our policy.

denke ich von zwei möglichen Übersetzungen: Politik, Richtlinien.

Welche wäre die passendere Übersetzung?

Comment: Wenn es um tiefere Werte gehen wenn du auf Englisch "policy" schreibst und nicht nur z.B. administrative Verfahrensweise (Richtlinien), dann würde ich es vielleicht sogar eher mit "Grundsätzen" übersetzen: "Es ist gegen unsere Grundsätze Behinderte zu benachteiligen."

Comment: Ohne weiteren Kontext kann "policy" hier so ziemlich alles bedeuten.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hier wäre „Richtlinie“ der passendere Begriff. „Politik“ würde sich eher als Übersetzung anbieten, wenn mit der „policy“ eine Strategie oder Agenda gemeint ist.

Answer (score 3):

Wie so oft bietet es sich auch hier an, den Anglizismus verwenden. Ich denke, *Policy* ist verbreitet und verständlich.

*Policy* wird darüberhinaus weder durch "Unternehmensphilosophie" noch durch "Leitlinien" noch durch "Unternehmensgrundsätze" adäquat übersetzt. Eine *Policy* ist eine bestimmte Art und Weise, mit bestimmten Situationen umzugehen. Anders als *Leitlinien* oder *Grundsätze* ist eine Policy aber nicht notwendigerweise kodifiziert. "Leitlinien" und "Grundsätze" bezeichnen also das, was niedergeschrieben ist, "Policy" kann auch das beschreiben, was tatsächliche Praxis ist, etwas, was man vielleicht "betriebliche Übung" nennen würde.

Im Englischen sagt man ohne Weiteres: *That's not our policy.*, im Deutschen sagt man: *Das widerspricht unseren Leitlinien*. Das zeigt, dass *policy* eine Menge von Verhaltensweisen bezeichnet und *Leitlinien* eine Menge von Regeln. Ich denke, darin liegt der wesentliche Unterschied. Es kann Fälle geben, in denen "Leitlinien" die richtige Übersetzung ist. Oft wird aber der Anglizismus die korrektere Übersetzung sein.

*Unternehmensphilosophie* ist deutlich allgemeiner und als *Policy* und bezeichnet eher die ideellen Grundsätze eines Unternehmens.

Comment: "Unternehmensphilosophie" ist definitiv zu hoch aufgehängt. Dennoch hat es sich im Deutschen etabliert, von "Unternehmensrichtlinien" oder  "Unternehmensgrundsätzen" zu sprechen. Ein Anglizismus ist hier nicht nötig.

Comment: @KritikerderElche Danke für den Hinweis. Ich habe die Begründung noch erweitert.

Comment: *policy* ist im Englischen ein absoluter Allerweltsbegriff und kann alles mögliche bedeuten (von "Taktik" über "Regel" bis zu "Leitsatz" und ganz einfach "Politik"). Wir haben im Deutschen wesentlich treffendere Begriffe für all diese Dinge. Im Interesse einer präzisen Sprache rate ich dringend davon ab, den Anglizismus zu verwenden (außer natürlich, man möchte absichtlich unkonkret sein).

Answer (score 1):

Ich schlage *Unternehmensgrundsätze* vor. Zitat aus [BWL-LEXIKON.DE](https://www.bwl-lexikon.de/wiki/unternehmensgrundsaetze/):

> Die in der Unternehmensphilosophie ausgearbeiteten Leitlinien werden durch die Unternehmensgrundsätze aufgenommen und in praktisch umsetzbare Regeln umgewandelt. Für die Mitarbeiter stellen sie Handlungsrichtlinien dar, genauso wie sie bei der strategischen Planung durch die Führungskräfte berücksichtigt werden müssen.

Eine Google-Suche nach "Unternehmensgrundsätze" liefert ca. 172.000 Ergebnisse.

Je nach Kontext kann auch [*Unternehmensphilosophie* oder *Unternehmensleitbild*](https://www.denk-neu.com/unterschied-unternehmensphilosophie-und-unternehmensleitbild/) angemessen sein.

> **Erst die Philosophie, dann das Leitbild**
> Allgemein ist die Philosophie eines Unternehmens das, wofür der Betrieb steht. Es sind seine Alleinstellungsmerkmale, seine Werte und sein öffentliches Erscheinungsbild. Die Unternehmensphilosophie ist die grundlegende Basis für alle Aktionen und Handlungen, die Chefs, Führungskräfte und Mitarbeiter vornehmen – und im Idealfall wirklich leben. Der Unterschied zwischen Unternehmensphilosophie und Unternehmensleitbild zeigt sich deswegen in erster Linie darin, dass die Philosophie das Leitbild bedingt. Mit anderen Worten: Ohne gemeinsame Wertevorstellungen kann es kein gemeinsames Leitbild geben.